# Machine learning / statistical model of a deterministic process: how large must my training set be to ensure almost perfect accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model, logistic-regression

This may be a silly question, but if I got a deterministic process, for instance, a function (in the mathematical sense) that happens to be computationally expensive to evaluate, and I decided to approximate it with logistic regression, an artificial neural network, or any kind of machine learning model:

1. Is there several (random and continuous) training instances that can ensure "almost" perfect accuracy for my learning model? If yes, how to compute this number?
2. In general, can I expect at least "better" models if the process is deterministic?
3. Is overfitting a problem in this case? My intuition somehow says no, but I cannot prove it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, there is no threshold for the amount of training data that can ensure ~100% accuracy for arbitrary models and data. Not all models have the same capacity (e.g. linear regression can represent linear functions on the inputs) and not all deterministic process have the same complexity. Also, not every sample of a process input and output values reflect all the possible cases that can be. This entirely depends on the model and the data.
2. No, a deterministic model does not necessarily imply that models achieve high accuracy. Like the first point, whether models are able to achieve better accuracy or not depends entirely on the model we choose and the data.
3. Yes, overfitting is a problem in your case. Achieving high accuracy on the training dataset does not equate to achieving high accuracy on the whole input data domain. If at inference time the model sees data that it has not seen during training, overfitting is always a risk.

Also, take into account that there are multiple sources of stochasticity. A deterministic process lacks [aleatoric uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_quantification#Aleatoric_and_epistemic) but may have epistemic uncertainty, e.g. stochastic measurement errors, lack of data in some areas of the process' input/output domains.

All these factors don't necessarily mean that using a machine learning model to represent a deterministic process is a bad idea. Just that machine learning is not a silver bullet for representing any process, either deterministic or not. In this situation, the model's performance should be evaluated with the same rigour as with any other stochastic process.

As a side note, if you know a closed-form expression for your deterministic process, maybe you can go for a mathematical approximation like the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series), the [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), or the [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant).

Comment: Thank you, @noe. My question was too broad, so I understand that it all depends on the choices that I've left unspecified. But what you said leads me to conclude that (in general) knowing that a process is deterministic has no utility at all when it comes to ML approximations, is this your conclusion also?

Comment: No, I don't think that. It all boils down to the specific case. Normally, any domain knowledge is helpful in selecting the model with the appropriate induction bias so, knowing that the process is deterministic, along with information about the nature of the problem, may give valuable clues for which models may be appropriate and which ones maybe not so much.